# keras load model and test the model seq2seq

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, seq2seq

i have trained the machine translation build in keras with deep learning

and i saved the whole mode as **model.h5**

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

and now i want load the model and test it

example takes the input from the user and then translate it

it is seq2seq  how to load the **model.h5** and how to test it ?

example in a new python file i will load the model.h5 and test it

**model.load('model.h5')**

Comment: Check this out. It demonstrates how to use `load_model()` to restore seq2seq models. --> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq_restore.py

Comment: thanks for relying i have seen it but it came from the original of keras documentaion but mine is difference but still is a seq2seq model and the whole model saved as .h5 and the weights saved as hdf5 with each epoch and i want to restore h5 and use it again